# python defaultdict get method return value

Tags: python

Using Python 2 and wondering why `False` other than `True` is printed? I think we have key value `2`, so `get(2)` should return `True`? Thanks.

```
import collections

dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
dict[1]=[1,2,3]
dict[2]=[4,5,6]

print dict

if dict.get(2) == True:
    print True
else:
    print False
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: read the [get()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) documentation

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ, vote up. But why `if 2 in dict == True:` also returns False?

Comment: @LinMa: That's a [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in). Stop comparing things to `True` or `False`; it's almost never a good idea, especially with `==`.

Comment: Are you drunk my friend? `if 2 in dict == True` makes no sense for the compiler. If you want to achieve the goal you are looking for, you need to type `if (2 in dict) == True:`

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ, nice catch, I thought `2 in dict` should have a prioritization in compiler so I missed `()`, vote up. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use python built-in names as your variable names.

`My_dict.get()` doesn't return `True`, it returns the value of passed key if it exist otherwise if you don't pass a default argument it will return `None` by default.

If you want to check the validation of `My_dict.get()` you can do:

```
if My_dict.get(2):
    print True
else:
    print False
```

Or just:

```
print bool(My_dict.get(2))
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> 
>>> my_dict = defaultdict()
>>> 
>>> my_dict[1]=[1,2,3]
>>> my_dict[2]=[4,5,6]
>>> 
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(None, {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5, 6]})
>>> 
>>> 2 in my_dict
True
>>> 
>>> my_dict.get(2)
[4, 5, 6]
>>> 
>>> my_dict.get(7, None)
>>> bool(my_dict.get(7, None))
False
```

Comment: Thanks Kasramvd, vote up. What is the return value I should check if a key does not exist?

Comment: No: what if `dict[2]` is `None`, `False` or any other value that evaluates to `False`? You should use `2 in dict`.

Comment: @Kasramvd, thanks and vote up. But why `if 2 in dict == True:` also returns False?

Comment: @ThinkChaos, I think your reply makes sense, as I tried `if dict.get(2, None) == True:` in my example, it returns False. :)

Comment: @Kasramvd, I tried `if dict.get(2, None) == True:` in my example, it returns False. It seems it does not work? :)

Comment: `dict.get()` does not raise a `KeyError`. That's the point of using `dict.get()` in the first place. And there's no need to pass `None`, as that's the default value that gets returned if the key isn't found.

Comment: All I said was refusing of comparing the `dict.get` with boolean objects. Check out the example.

Comment: `get` returns `None` if a key isn't found. You don't need to specify it. It's just noise.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Indeed, I was fixing that, I mixed it up with myself overridden object. Thanks for note.

Comment: @Kasramvd, thanks for all the help. Mark your reply as answer.